# why is javascript-function just executed if an alert() is put at the beginning?

Tags: javascript, json, callback, seam

```
var callback = function(result){
             //alert(result);
             var json = eval('('+result+')');
             if(json.criticalerror==true) dialogCriticalError(json.errormessage);
                else{
                    if(json.error==true) dialogError(json.errormessage);
                    else{
                        // Do something else
                    }
                }
         };
```

When this callback-function is executed the "*Do something else*" part is called without problems. But in the case the **json.error** is ***true*** the dialogError-function is not executed. I've checked the transmitted JSON in Firebug. Everything is ok. The result is a JSON string as it should be.

The interesting thing is, that it actually **is** executed if i call the JSON-response with an alert() function at the beginning of the callback function. I'm new to JavaScript and probably missing something obvious but i just can't figure it out. Where's the bug?

---

EDIT:

It seems the problem is the time. If i put a 100ms delay between the JSON-result and the actual callback, everything works perfectly. But this can't be right... I'm kind of clueless.

(Oh and by the way: the communication is done by JBoss Seam Remoting)

The whole function looks like that:

```
        function nextNode() {
         var callback = function(result){
             var json = JSON.parse(result);
             if (json.criticalerror==true) {
                    dialogCriticalError(json.errormessage);
                }else if (json.error==true) {
                    dialogError(json.errormessage);
                }else {
                        document.getElementById('currentTree').innerHTML = json.state;
                        document.getElementById('countTrees').innerHTML = json.amountSteps;
                        document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.importGraph(json.tree);
                        document.getElementById('relevantnode').innerHTML = json.node;
                        createNodeBar(json);
                }                
         };
        manager.nextNode(callback);
    }
```

The manager object is provided by the Seam Framework through the following function:

```
var manager = Seam.Component.getInstance("solverTreeStructure");
```

---

---

LAST EDIT:

Okay now i got the definite source of the problem. Its not not the Seam Remoting but the dialogError() function and the library it uses to display the dialog.

The dialogError() function looks like that:

```
function dialogError(error){
        TINY.box.show({html:error,width:250,height:100,close:true,mask:true,opacity:20,topsplit:3})
    }
```

It uses a small dialog library called TINYBOX. Now this library offers a variety of parameters to configure the dialog boxes. The 'mask' parameter caused all the trouble. It is resposible for darkening the background of the dialog box. If its turned on, TINYBOX needs a start-delay in order to work with the callback function. (i have NO idea why)

But for those who like riddles:

Thats the library. Its very small and clear. Unfortunately my JavaScript skills are not yet sophisticated enough to understand it.
http://www.scriptiny.com/2011/03/javascript-modal-windows/

Thats the answer. Have a nice day folks! ;)

Comment: Why are you using `eval()` instead of `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: Hmm...probably because this was the first solution i found ^^. I changed the eval() part to JSON.parse(result) but the problem is still here. :( The alert() muste have done somtehing to the response so its beeing recognized differently. But what?

Comment: How/when are you calling your callback function?

Comment: @RoToRa: I added the complete function into the question...

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'm not familiar with Seam. My general guess: The callback function is somehow called too early - possibly not as a callback function, that's why a delay with the alert works. I can't say how this is happening.

Comment: hmm...yeah i guessed something like that too. but this would mean that the callback function is beeing called without parameters but the seam documentation says that its executed AFTER the sever method has finished its work... anyways, thanks for your clue...

Answer (score 2):

Just a general advice: do not mix blocks with and without `{}`. The following form is much more readable and you can pinpoint your problem quicker.

```
console.log(json);
if (json.criticalerror == true) {

    console.log("criticalerror");
    dialogCriticalError(json.errormessage);

} else if (json.error == true) {

    console.log("error");
    dialogError(json.errormessage);

} else {

    console.log("something else");
    // Do something else
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice... Its definately better like that :)
But the problem is still there :(

Comment: @Jonny I added some `console.log` lines. They work in modern browsers, much better then alert(). Maybe it will help to identify what's going wrong.

Comment: OK, now i found out that the reason it works with the alert() is not the alert but the time which passes before i am able to close the dialog. I tried putting a "setTimeout" between the JSON-repsonse and the call of the callback function. RESULT: 100ms were enough and it worked. Now the question is. WHY??    (@vbence: Thanks for your advice. I will try that in future...)

Comment: @Jonny The secrtet may lie in how you set up your event handler.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems the problem is the time. If i
>   put a 100ms delay between the
>   JSON-result and the actual callback,
>   everything works perfectly. But this
>   can't be right... I'm kind of
>   clueless.

Sounds like your doing *asynchronous* (ajax) communication. WHere is the rest of your code that asks the server for some data. Your handling the result before the server gives it to you. This explains the delay.

Comment: yes, it's asynchronous. but this is something the seam framework handles in the background. in the documentation it says that the callback function is beeng called right after the server method has finished the work. so normally this shouldn't be an issue. but of course i don't know how exactly it works in the background... but it helps to know that there is no problem with the javascript itself :) thanks so far!